# Is it possible to subscribe to changes in Azure DocumentDb?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Is there some way to subscribe to changes in an Azure DocumentDb? For example, something similar to SQL Server SQL Dependency.  If there is nothing "built-in", is there a recommended approach to solving this problem?

**Update**: As of May 2017 Change Feed is available.  See more here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to subscribe to changes but it's a frequently requested feature (see votes for it [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/6328399-changes-feed?tracking_code=c73abecb36e71c2f1f810bd104481e2c) which also shows it as "under review"). I heard a while back that Azure Functions also wants this for their DocumentDB connection so maybe that will help get it from "under review" to "in progress". Go vote it up to help.

Until then, most people poll the collection using either the _ts field or with their own time series sequential field. However, there is no guarantee that a document with an earlier _ts won't show up later with default eventual or even session consistency so you have to work around that usually by going back in time and then checking for duplicates (idempotency).